# normalization of a curve, simplest example

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am learning about normalization of nodal curves and I am trying to understand the simplest example: $xy=0$

As far as I understand its coordinate ring is $k[x]\oplus k[y]$ (let $k$ be an algebraically closed field)

If I look at a smooth point, $(1,0)$ for instance, then its local ring is $k(x)\oplus k[y]$ since it is just localizing $k[x]\oplus k[y]$ on the ideal (y). and its ring of fractions is $k(x)\oplus k(y)$ I think that indeed $k(x)\oplus k[y]$ is integrally closed in $k(x)\oplus k(y)$ as desired.

Now for the nodal point $(0,0)$, its local ring is $k[x]\oplus k[y]$  but I can not say whether it is integrally closed or not. Can someone help me? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you think it's $k[x] \oplus k[y]$? (Maybe one should use $\times$ instead. In any case, I don't think it's right.)

Comment: The coordinate ring of the variety $Y =Z(xy)$ (meaning the set of zeroes of the polynomial xy in k^2)  is $k[x,y]/xy \cong k[x]\oplus k[y]$, isn't it? please correct me.

Comment: Can you write down that isomorphism $\cong$? What goes where?

Comment: $k[x,y]=\{1, x, y, xy, x^2, x^2y , ...\}$ hence quotienting by $xy$ gives me ${1,x, y, 1, x^2, x, ... }$ and then the iso is clear.

Comment: I disagree with your statement somewhat, but anyway: I agree that one can naturally write down a $k$-basis for $k[x,y]/(xy)$ consisting of the residue classes of $1,x^n,y^m$ with $n,m\geq 1$. That does not mean that your ring is $k[x] \times k[y]$. You've said nothing about the multiplicative structure. Where do the elements $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ in $k[x] \times k[y]$ get sent in $k[x,y]/(xy)$?

Comment: @user92135 the problem is that you have only written down a bijection of sets; you need to check that it is an algebraic isomorphism

Comment: Consider $f: k[x]\oplus k[y] \longrightarrow k[x,y]$ where $f(p(x))=p(x)$ and $f(p(y))=p(y)$ meaning $p(x)$ any polynomial in variable $x$ and $p(y)$ any in $y$. Then $\ker (f)=(xy)$ and the isomorphism theorem does the rest.

Comment: $f(p(x),p(y))=p(x)+p(y)$ ok I'm in trouble here, lets see if I can make it.

Comment: $\times$ is not the coproduct in the category of $k$-algebras (this is why I'm against using $\oplus$ the way you're using it). You have defined a map of vector spaces but it is not a ring homomorphism. Concretely, check whether $f((1,0) \cdot (0,1)) = f(0,0)$. Does that make sense?

Comment: But it is the definition of a quotient of a ring by its ideal, isn't? I mean, $k[x,y] /(xy)= \{ p\in k[x,y] mod (xy) \}$

Comment: anyway lets make the question simpler, is $k[x]\oplus k[y]$ integrally closed?

Comment: If one follows the definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrally_closed_domain#Normal_rings), then yes, $k[x] \times k[y]$ is integrally closed. The corresponding geometric object is the disjoint union of two copies of $\mathbb A^1$, so it's very nice and smooth.

Comment: ok, then going backwards this is the normalization of my node. Now I need to know what is the local ring on the (0,0) of my curve, and it seems everything goes with understanding the coordinate ring $k[x,y]/xy$

Comment: also how do you prove that it is integrally closed? is the direct sum (or product) of PID a PID? what criteria?

Comment: I think I have the solution for the isomorphism: a polynomial $k[x,y]/(xy)$ $f+(xy)$ can be written as $g(x)+h(y)+(xy)$ so then we construct a map 
$$k[x,y]/xy\longrightarrow k[x]\oplus k[y]$$ by sending $f+(xy)$ to $(g,h)$

Comment: and yes, I see, $k[x]\oplus k[y]$ is of course integrally closed and the localization at the ideal $(x,y)$ gives itself, so it seems that already my node in the cross of two affine lines is telling me that there are two lines. I mean, maybe the example is too patological to actually "see" the normalisation.

Comment: by the way, as it gives two "charts", that is the reason I use $\oplus$ but of course I understand why you like $\times$ you maybe thinking on $A^1\times A^1$

Comment: (1) I'm not sure how you're concluding that this is the normalization. You'll have to tell me what your definition of normalization is first, I guess. (2) I don't like $\oplus$ because I think it suggests a universal property that $A \times B$ simply does not have. You ran into this already: you tried to specify a ring homomorphism $A \times B \to C$ by specifying $A \to C$ and $B \to C$. (3) I want to emphasize that no isomorphism between $k[x,y]/(xy)$ and $k[x] \times k[y]$ can exist. (4) Are your $g$ and $h$ unique? (5) $((x,0), (0,y))$ is not a prime ideal in your $k[x] \times k[y]$.

Answer (score 5):

I've tried to read the comments, but it's not clear to me if $$K[X,Y]/(XY)\not\simeq K[X]\oplus K[Y]$$ is settled down or not. The argument is very simple: the first ring has only two idempotents, while the second has four.

In your example the smooth point $(1,0)$ corresponds to the maximal ideal $\mathfrak m=(x-1,y)$ and $R_{\mathfrak m}=K[X]_{(X-1)}$ is a DVR, so it is integrally closed.

Comment: which are these 4 idempotents?
how do you conclude that the coordinate ring is K[x]? You should localize the coordinate ring don't you?

Comment: @user92135 One of them is $(1,0)$. Can you find the other three? Isn't $R_m$ a localization of the coordinate ring?

Comment: you mean (1,0) (0,1) (1,1) and (0,0)? how do you know that in that quotient you only have (1,1) and (0,0)?

Comment: $R=K[X,Y]/(XY)$ and $x,y$ denote the residue classes of $X,Y$.